# Passing component as props and using it in event

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I'm creating a tab styled nav. And I've passed the tabs and their content as children. As shown below

```
import "./App.css";
import Tabs from "./TranslationPopoverCardComponent/Tabs";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Tabs>
          <span label="Gator">
            <button>Butotn here</button>
          </span>
          <span label="Croc">
            After 'while, <em>Crocodile</em>!
          </span>
          <span label="Sarcosuchus">Nothing to see here,</span>
        </Tabs>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Inside the Tabs component.

```
class Tabs extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      //setting default open tab
      activeTab: this.props.children[0],
    };
    this.changeTab = this.changeTab.bind(this);
  }

  changeTab(e) {
    this.setState({ activeTab: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    const tabs = this.props.children.map((child) => {
      return (
        <span>
          <button value={child} onClick={this.changeTab}>  // this line here
            {child.props.label}
          </button>
        </span>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div>
        {tabs}
        <br />
        {this.state.activeTab}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Tabs;
```

The default tab and loads as expected showing a button. And then, when i click another tab the text doesnt load. Shows [object Object] . Can I not pass props.children as props of a component and then set it as a state via event? (what did I do wrong? )

I've tried on that line over there replacing `child` with with `child.props.children` but then the button component doesn't renders and shows [object Object] and others work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that `inputs/buttons` value  doesn't store an object, value is always a string that's why you are seeing `[object,object]` when clicking each tab button `(try console.log(typeof e.target.value))`.

plus you don't need to use value you can instead pass child directly to the function like this:

```
 <button onClick={() => setActive(child)}>
```

here the full [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-merkle-tgif8?file=/src/Tabs.js)

Answer (score 0):

Use this in onClick

```
 onClick={() => this.changeTab(child)}
```

and modify the handler as

```
  changeTab(e) {
    this.setState({ activeTab: e });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass index while clicking on tab i.e

```
const tabs = this.props.children.map((child,i) => {
      return (
        <span>
          <button value={child} onClick={ () => this.changeTab(i)}> 
            {child.props.label}
          </button>
        </span>
      );
    });
```

and inside change Tab do this:

```
changeTab = (i) =>  {
    this.setState({ activeTab: this.props.children[i] });
  }
```

Here is full code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class Tabs extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      //setting default open tab
      activeTab: this.props.children[0]
    };
    this.changeTab = this.changeTab.bind(this);
  }

  changeTab = (i) => {
    this.setState({ activeTab: this.props.children[i] });
  };

  render() {
    const tabs = this.props.children.map((child, i) => {
      return (
        <span>
          <button value={child} onClick={() => this.changeTab(i)}>
            {child.props.label}
          </button>
        </span>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div>
        {tabs}
        <br />
        {this.state.activeTab}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Tabs>
        <span label="Gator">
          <button>Button here</button>
        </span>
        <span label="Croc">
          After 'while, <em>Crocodile</em>!
        </span>
        <span label="Sarcosuchus">Nothing to see here,</span>
      </Tabs>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-kepler-sr4pz?file=/src/App.js:0-1081